# How can I close my accordion in a normal slideUp behavior ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I have an accordion.

[image]

---

If I click on **View Report** - it will expand like this

[image]

---

If I click **Hide Details** - it will be back to original state.

[image]

---

**JS**

```
$saReport.click(function() {
    console.log('R');
    $saReport.addClass('hidden'); //hide
    $saHide.removeClass('hidden'); //show
});

$saHide.click(function() {
    console.log('H');
    $saHide.addClass('hidden');
    $saReport.removeClass('hidden');
    $('.panel-collapse').removeClass('in');
});
```

---

**Result**

My accordion is closing very quick, like flashing hide. 
How can I close my accordion in a normal slideUp behavior ?

Any hints / helps / suggestions on that will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be usefull if you could post some relevant html.

If you you desire a simple slide behaviour you could either use the [bootstrap accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion) which is quite well documented.
If you want to implement it yourself, you could simply use the jquery `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` methods, i.e.:

```
$saReport.click(function() {
    console.log('R');
    $saReport.addClass('hidden'); //hide
    $saHide.removeClass('hidden'); //show

    // slide down your report (show)
    $('.your-report-container').slideDown(400);
});

$saHide.click(function() {
    console.log('H');
    $saHide.addClass('hidden');
    $saReport.removeClass('hidden');
    $('.panel-collapse').removeClass('in');

    // slide up your report (hide)
    $('.your-report-container').slideUp(400);
});
```

These slide methods allow you to pass a parameter, which is the time in ms for the animation. The default is 400.